# Where are the layout defaults in Twenty Twenty Two coming from?

Tags: block-editor, theme-twenty-twenty-two

When I'm editing the template for a Single Post using the Twenty Twenty Two theme, there's a layout option for the post content block that says it will inherit the default layout. Where is that default coming from? Is that a site-wide default or a theme default?

Here's a screenshot that shows what I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> there's a layout option for the post content block that says it will inherit the default layout. Where is that default coming from?

In block themes, the default [layout settings](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/theme-json/#layout) (`contentSize` and `wideSize`) can be found in the `theme.json` file in the root theme folder, e.g. at `wp-content/themes/twentytwentytwo/theme.json` in Twenty Twenty-Two. <sub>[See source on GitHub for WordPress v5.9.3 & Twenty Twenty-Two v1.1](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.9.3/wp-content/themes/twentytwentytwo/theme.json#L203-L206)</sub>

And if the `layout` option does not exist in the `theme.json` file, i.e. `settings.layout` is not defined, then the "Layout" panel (in the Block Settings sidebar) *will not include* the toggle labeled "Inherit default layout".

Answer (score 1):

It's not specific to Twenty Twenty Two - the [post content block layout option](https://wordpress.org/support/article/post-content-block/) allows you to override the default width defined by the active theme.